# Can't build notcommerce project under appharbor

Tags: nopcommerce, appharbor

I used nopcommerce to create a store. And now I want to deploy it on appharbor. But I have a small issue: nopcommerce hasn't **.sln** file (which have list of files) and appharbor can't build project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your repository contains no solution files, it will be treated as a WebMatrix project and deployed straight up. This works fine for Orchard CMS, for example -- [see this guide for more details](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/running-orchard-on-appharbor). There's more on the [AppHarbor solution file convention here](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/build-process-and-solution-file-convention).

You can make the source distribution (which includes a solution file) of nopCommerce build on AppHarbor though. Here's a [Git patch with the necessary modifications](https://gist.github.com/1324012).

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)

Comment: Many thanks you, you have a good service! I'm new to git(previous I used svn) and need investigate how to make this patch, but I think I'll find solution myself. Again, many-many thanks.

Comment: so you make this patch for full sources solution right? Because I'm using builded project(downloaded from webmatrix) and when I trying to apply patch I receieving following error: Applying: Make solution build on AppHarbor
fatal: sha1 information is lacking or useless (Presentation/Nop.Web.Framework/Nop.Web.Framework.csproj).
Repository lacks necessary blobs to fall back on 3-way merge.
Cannot fall back to three-way merge.
Patch failed at 0001 Make solution build on AppHarbor

Comment: Yes, the  patch is against the 2.20 sources