# 403 Error (Forbidden) when trying to view my MVC4 application on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, http-status-code-403, appharbor

I'm new to both ASP.net and AppHarbor. I also have never deployed an ASP.net application before.

I've set up an MVC4 website using the Visual Studio 2012 release candidate and it is near completion. Locally, it is working fine / as expected.

To send the client a current progress demo, I've been advised that I should use [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com) to host the application / website.

I've gone through the process of setting up a Git repository and connecting that with AppHarbor. I then used the `Build -> Publish Selection` option in Visual Studio to create a 'Web Deploy Package' within my local copy of the repository. Finally, I pushed the files (shown below) that were created to the repository and AppHarbor listed the commit as 'Active'.

[image]

> However, when I click *Go to your application*, all I get is [this magnificent 403 page](http://barslide.apphb.com/).

I've tried a bunch of things (none of which have worked so far) that I've seen in forums (including here and AppHarbor support), including:

- [Adding a `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425574/mvc4-http-error-403-14-forbidden)
- [Ensuring I didn't have multiple web projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954765/appharbor-nopcommerce-running-issue).
- Checking and confirming that there are no errors listed in AppHarbor.
- I've turned [CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) off, yielding no differences.

I haven't touched any of the `.config` stuff since I began the project (because I don't know how to use them yet). Perhaps I've just not added something blatantly obvious in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the Web Publish stuff when you want to deploy to AppHarbor. AppHarbor takes your source code straight up, builds it, tests it and deploys it.

Here's a guide on [deploying your first app on AppHarbor using Git](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/deploying-your-first-application-using-git). There's also a video on the AppHarbor front page that you can check out.

Comment: I gave that a shot one of the first tries and it failed. [Here is the log from that attempt](https://appharbor-logs.s3.amazonaws.com/32/7bc30f-c722-4d54-86fc-a09f01814cf6/321745.msbuild.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJDP3GVM5BQG2W7HA&Expires=1343800859&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3Dbarslide-buildlog-5fc150a.txt&Signature=YnwUF4Y05KeAuMIIWb73J0wI0ds%3D) if that helps at all. There seems to have been 1 warning (though there are no warnings when I run it locally).

Comment: The link you posted expires, can you show add the log to the question text?

Comment: The problem is likely that you're relying on .NET 4.5 RC assemblies which are not on AppHarbor. You should re-target to 4.0.

Comment: That seems to have worked, however now a large portion of the images aren't there... Any ideas? http://barslide.apphb.com/

Comment: Have you marked the image files as "Content" in your project? There are more debugging suggestions in the FAQ: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/